# TCL: reading next line of a file once a certain pattern has been identified

Tags: tcl, data-files

I have this data

# Curve 0 of 2, 7 points
# x y xlow xhigh type
**20.781**  1  20.781  20.781
20.8102  10  20.8102  20.8102
20.8395  18  20.8395  20.8395
20.8687  13  20.8687  20.8687
20.898  15  20.898  20.898
20.9273  18  20.9273  20.9273
**20.9565**  13  20.9565  20.9565

# Curve 1 of 2, 7 points
# x y xlow xhigh type
**21.635**  2  21.635  21.635
21.6625  19  21.6625  21.6625
21.6899  29  21.6899  21.6899
21.7173  63  21.7173  21.7173
21.7447  137  21.7447  21.7447
21.7721  168  21.7721  21.7721
**21.7996**  109  21.7996  21.7996

All the information is an unique file, i.e block data are separated by three blank lines.
I want to collect the information that is just at the beginning of the next line that has characters *# x y xlow xhigh type*. Also I want to collect the information that is at the end of each block. In other words, I want to print on screen the values that are in bold letter (20.781 20.9565 21.635 21.7996).

I wrote these lines of code but I don't know how to print the info that is just below the characters # x y.

```
set input [open "dataHist.dat" r]

while { [gets $input line] != -1 } {
   if { [string range 0 4] == "# x y"} {
      
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a case where you want to save the _previous_ line: when the previous line contains "# x y", print the _current_ line; when the current line is blank (or you're at end-of-file), print the _previous_ line

Answer (score 1):

Since the first line of each block tells you long it is, you can use that to tell which lines you want to extract the first number from:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

proc must_gets {ch var_} {
    upvar $var_ var
    if {[gets $ch var] < 0} {
        error "Premature end of file"
    }
}

proc extract_numbers {filename} {
    set ch [open $filename]
    try {
        set nums {}
        while {[gets $ch line] >= 0} {
            if {[regexp {^# Curve \d+ of \d+, (\d+) points} $line -> nPoints]} {
                must_gets $ch line ;# Discard '# x y ...' line.                                                                                                                                                                                  
                must_gets $ch line ;# First point line
                # Extract first element of it                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                lappend nums [lindex [split $line] 0]                                                                                                                                                                                            
                # Read remaining point lines                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                for {set n 2} {$n <= $nPoints} {incr n} {
                    must_gets $ch line
                }
                # And extract first element of last one                                                                                                                                                                                   
                lappend nums [lindex [split $line] 0]
            }
        }
        return $nums
    } finally {
        chan close $ch
    }
}

# 20.781 20.9565 21.635 21.7996                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
puts [extract_numbers dataHist.dat]
```